# Set variable value in nested function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to access variables inside a typescript class. 
The first one `checkLUCE1` is easily editable adding `this`.

The second one `checkLUCE2` is inside another function and i don't know how to set a new value for it:

```
export class ServiziConfigurazioneComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private savelocal: SavelocaleService,
          private globals: GlobalsService) { }


checkLUCE1:boolean = false;
checkLUCE2:boolean = false;

handleFileSelect(evt,servizio,i){

    let target = evt.target || evt.srcElement || evt.currentTarget;
    let idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    let value = idAttr.nodeValue;
    let obj:any;

    document.getElementById(value+'-image').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(value+'-loading').style.display = "block";

    let files = evt.target.files;
    let file = files[0];
    this.checkLUCE1 = true; //HERE I CAN SET THE VALUE

    if (files && file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {
            (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById(value+'-image-file')).src  = reader.result;
            let binaryString = reader.result;
            let base64textString = btoa(binaryString);
            //console.log(base64textString);

            let obj = {};
            obj['file-'+servizio+'-'+i]= {
                'file' : base64textString
            };
            checkLUCE2= true; //HERE I CAN'T SET THE VALUE

            localStorage.setItem('currentUserLuceFile-'+i,base64textString);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);


        document.getElementById(value+'-image').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById(value+'-loading').style.display = "none";

        //this.savelocal.write('currentUserOfferta',JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrow functions in order to achive this. So instead of declaring your function like `reader.onload = function() {...}` you can use `reader.onload = () => {...}`. Have a look at [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Bla%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20luce1%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22sdfgsy%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20luce2%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22sdfysd%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(this.luce1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20anonymous%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20this.luce2%20%3D%20%22Success%22%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anonymous()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(this.luce2)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bla%20%3D%20new%20Bla()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Abla.doSomething()%3B).

```
class Bla {

    // Your variables
    luce1: string = "sdfgsy";
    luce2: string = "sdfysd";

    // In your case that was "handleFileSelect"
    public doSomething() {
        alert(this.luce1);
        // this is what you are looking for. Inside the arrow function you can set the class level variable
        let anonymous = () => { this.luce2 = "Success" }

        anonymous();

        alert(this.luce2);
    }

}

let bla = new Bla();

bla.doSomething();
```

Comment: @SergioGandrus You have to omit the word `function`! Just remove it. It has to be `reader.onload = () => {...}`

Comment: @SergioGandrus Great! Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to solve it:

Store the context in a variable:

```
var self=this;

document.onload=function () {
  self.myAttribute=...
};
```

Use arrow functions, where the context is set in declaration time, not in execution time:

```
document.onload=() => {
  this.myAttribute=...
}
```

Bind the context to the function using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
document.onload=(function () {
  this.myAttribute=...
}).bind(this);
```